# Why is MsBuild's ItemGroup->EndWith not working for '.exe'?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I'm trying to make an item group of dll's and exe's but filtering out any msi's and test.dll's.

The following snippet doesn't include the .exe in the UniqueAssemblies itemgroup. It does contain all the dll's and removes the msi as expected though. UniqueCompiledFiles does contain all the expected output files (.test.dll, .dll, .msi, .exe)

```
<Target Name="CustomCompile">
<MSBuild
  BuildInParallel="true"
  Projects="@(ProjectFiles)"
  Properties="$(ProjectProperties)"
>
  <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="CompiledFiles" />
</MSBuild>
<RemoveDuplicates Inputs="@(CompiledFiles)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Filtered" ItemName="UniqueCompiledFiles" />
</RemoveDuplicates>

<ItemGroup>
  <UniqueAssemblies
    Include="%(UniqueCompiledFiles.Identity)"
    Condition=" '@(UniqueCompiledFiles->EndsWith('.dll'))' == 'true' " />
  <UniqueAssemblies
    Include="%(UniqueCompiledFiles.Identity)"
    Condition=" '@(UniqueCompiledFiles->EndsWith('.exe'))' == 'true' " />
</ItemGroup>
```

I also figured out this workaround that does properly filter the .exe.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <UniqueAssemblies2
      Include="%(UniqueCompiledFiles.Identity)"
      Condition=" $([System.String]::new('%(UniqueCompiledFiles.Identity)').EndsWith('.exe')) " />
</ItemGroup>
```

Found out the culprit lines that could be removed to fix the problem but it doesn't actually answer the question.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- Workaround for MSBuild defect: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/69 -->
  <UniqueCompiledFiles Include="Project\bin\release\Project.exe">
    <MSBuildSourceProjectFile>Project\Project.csproj</MSBuildSourceProjectFile>
    <Platform>x86</Platform>
  </UniqueCompiledFiles>
</ItemGroup>
```

Why is the `@(UniqueCompiledFiles->EndsWith('.exe'))` syntax not working as expected?

Comment: One difference is that first example tries to nest single quotes while the second does not. Try quoting with a back tick instead: ``EndsWith(`.dll`)``

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a [Property Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx) on an item (instead of a property).

You should be able to get the desired result by using something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <UniqueAssemblies2
    Include="%(UniqueCompiledFiles.Identity)"
    Condition=" '%(Extension)' == '.exe' " />
</ItemGroup>
```